# Sails js : linking with controller

Tags: sails.js

I have this controller and i want to hit the page to addClient which is in agencyclient directory in views directory.

```js
addAgencyClient: function (req, res) {
       res.view('');
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return the view addClient.ejs which is located in the agencyclient directory?

If that's correct you can do it like this:

```
addAgencyClient: function (req, res) {
    return res.view('agencyclient/addClient');
},
```